# Calculating distance to a path

Tags: math, language-agnostic, geometry

I have a set of points that form a path. I would like to determine the minimum distance from any given point to this path. The path might look something like this:

```
points = [
    [50, 58],
    [53, 67],
    [59, 82],
    [64, 75],
    [75, 73]
];
```

where the first value is the x coordinate and the second the y coordinate. The path is open ended (it will not form a closed loop) and is made of straight segments between the points.

So, given a point, eg. `[90, 84]`, how to calculate the shortest distance from that point to the path?

I'm not necessarily looking for a complete solution, but any pointers and ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: What does the path do between the points?  Straight line segments?

Comment: @recursive, yes, just plain straight lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to construct pathological cases in which the closest line segment to a point P connects two points which are themselves farther from P than any other points in the path. Therefore, unless I am missing something very subtle, you must calculate the distance to each line segment to get the shortest distance to the path.

Here is a simple example:

```
(5,1)-(4,2)-(1,3)-(20,3)-(15,2)-(14,1)
```

Given point (10,1), the closest distance to the path would be to the point (10,3), which is along the line segment (1,3)-(20,3), but those two points are farther from (10,1) than any other point in the path.

So I don't believe there are any shortcuts to the naïve algorithm of finding the distance to each line segment and taking the minimum.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing would be to find the closest point from a line (making the path) measure the distance and move on along the path (and store the point for shortest distance).

[image: demo]

Comment: +1 for your use of color and form. I am not sure the Internet is yet ready to contain the contents of your many scribbled notebooks, but perhaps HTML5 will get us closer to that goal, and the tyrrany of the linear paragraph and recurive outline will come to an end. :D

Answer (score 1):

The distance between a point and a line is given by:

d = |(x_2 - x_1)(y_1 - y_0) - (x_1 - x_0)(y_2 - y_1)| / sqrt((x_2 - x_1)^2 - (y_2 - y_1)^2),

which is an expansion of the dot product, where (x_0, y_0) are the coordinates of the point, and (x_1, y_1) & (x_2, y_2) are the endpoints of the line.

It would be pretty simple to calculate this for each set of points, and then just determine which one is the lowest. I'm not unconvinced there's not a more elegant way to do so, but I'm not aware of it. Though I'd love to see if someone here answers with one!

Edit: Sorry that the math in here looks so messy without formatting. Here's an image of what this equation looks like, done nicely:

[image: Point to line!]
<sub>(from MathWorld - A Wolfram Web Resource: [wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional/NumberedEquation8.gif))</sub>

Another edit: As Chris pointed out in his post, this doesn't work if the points are in-line, i.e., if the line is defined by (0,0)-(0,1) and the point by (0,10). Like he explains, you need to check to make sure that the point being looked at isn't actually on the "extended path" of line itself. If it is, then it's just the distance between the closer endpoint and the point. All credit to Chris!

Answer (score 1):

The distance from a point C to a line segment AB is the area of the parallelogram ABCC'.

[image: Area of a Parallelogram]

Answer (score 1):

So, I just though about it for a second. erekalper already posted the distance between a point and a line. However, the problem with this formula is that it assumes the line has infinite length, which is not the case for your problem. Just an example for the problem: Assume a simple line that goes from (0,0) to (0,1) and a point with coordinates (0,10). The formula posted above would return o distance of 0, because if you extend the line it would hit the point. Unfortunately, in your case the line ends at (0,1), thus the distance is actually 9.

Thus my algorithm would be: Check if the angles at the endpoints of your lines are <= 90°. If so, the shortest distance for this path will be computable by the formula already posted. If not, the shortest distance is the distance to one of the endpoints. Do this for all parts of the path, choose the minimum

Comment: Sorry, I think you must've misinterpreted the formula I posted? It definitely assumes two endpoints to any line, not infinite length. Unless I'm misunderstanding that you're saying...

Comment: @erekalper: You also used [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html) this formula, and I interprete it such that it creates a 90° angle to the line, and therefore assuming that the line is of infinite length

Comment: The first formula on the page assumes no endpoints, correct. But I referenced the second type that's listed there, where the line has a definite beginning and end. In that case, with some linear algebra, you can see that the line-point distance is found by projecting the distance between the point and an endpoint onto a vector that's perpendicular to the line. So that vector is at 90°, but the point itself doesn't have to be.

Comment: @erekalper: The 2nd formula just uses a line defined via 2 points, not necessarily endpoints. Just enter the example I posted in my answer. Your formula will return d = 0 instead of d = 9

Comment: Great Scott, you're right! I had totally forgotten an in-line case like that. Great call! +1!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use linear algebra (*shivers*) to calculate the distance from the point to each of the lines.

Here is a link to an article that describes the math: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128161848/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55501.html)

And here is a [pretty good library](https://web.archive.org/web/20130118133623/http://www.google.com:80/codesearch/p?hl=en#fL2ZJnj2jRI/lib/JigLibX/Geometry/Distance.cs&q=distance%20point%20line%20lang:c#&sa=N&cd=9&ct=rc). You need to look at the methods called `PointSegmentDistance`. A *segment* is apparently a line that begins at one point and ends at the second point, whereas a *line* ***has*** two points but continue in infinity.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out shortest distance to each line segment and then you choose the smallest distance. When you calculate the shortest distance, you need to find out the nearest point in the line segment. If the nearest point is not between the start and end point, you must use the distance to start or end point (whichever is the nearest).

[This page](http://Shortest%20Distance%20from%20a%20Point%20to%20a%20Line) has some formulas that you are likely to need.